# What does “soften the noodle” mean in Bad Santa 2?

Tags: meaning-in-context, slang

What does this expression mean in Bad Santa 2 Movie?

> Sunny Soke: Of course, it's harder for the girl because she's gotta
>   get off before the drugs **soften the noodle**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little [context](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=bad-santa-2):

> I think she roofied me.
>   Ah, rohypnol. Excellent icebreaker. Of course, it's harder for the girl because she's gotta get off
>   - before the drugs soften the noodle.
>   - Yeah.
>   (*It's not clear how the speeches are distributed, but that's not relevant here.*)

Rohypnol ("roofie") is the "date rape" drug, a tranquillizer employed illegally to render the victim incapable of resisting sexual assault and often to induce retrograde amnesia in the victim.

The speaker crassly observes that when a woman administers rohypnol to a man she must act quickly to achieve sexual satisfaction ("get off") before the drug makes him incapable of an erection ("before the drugs soften the noodle").